# How to store HashMap<Enum,String> in single row where each key of map is 1 to 1 to column name in row of this?

Tags: java, sql, orm

Let say we have legacy SQL table with more than 50 columns . 
with different representation in model.

- id timestamp (stored as separate fields)
- column_1 column_2 ... column_51 (stored as single map)

I would like to avoid generate field in java code for each of column from column_1 to column_51 . I would prefer rather use HashMap with enumaration as keys same as column name.

I would like store and read map from table without Boilerplate code  for store/read attributes map .  Instead i would like read write map in one step.

PS:

- MyBatis had parameterMap which would be good enough for this purpose but as it is now deprecated.
- Using any deprecated or alpha stage api is not an option.
- Changing database is not an option.

Comment: What have you tried? What are you having trouble with?  It seems pretty straight forward to me except a HashMap is going to have more code and runtime checks than a generated class.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a standard SQL query and then scan through the returned column metadata.

I can't remember the exact API off hand but you can query the column names from the result set, something like:

```
 metadata = results.getMetadata();

 for (int i=0;i<metadata.getColumnCount();i++) {
     map.put(metadata.getColumn(i).getName(), results.getString(i));
 }
```